Able to ping but not to browse on wired connection (Wi-Fi works OK)
I have Pop!_OS. 
I hardwired my laptop (using Ethernet)
to my Inseego M3000 cellular hot spot this morning
and noticed I wasn't able to browse. 
I could ping websites by name (google.com) no problem. 
I tried the fixes from can ping but not browse (on Ask Ubuntu), shown below, without avail.
When I unplugged my Ethernet and connected via Wi-Fi,
everything worked fine.
I have tried:

Pointing /etc/resolv.conf to systemd:
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf


Appending the line net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0 into /etc/sysctl.conf:
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0
sysctl -p


I have set my Inseego DNS to 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8
ip route show to default

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600 

The /etc/resolv.conf now reads:
nameserver 192.168.1.1
search .



In all of these cases, when connected to wired, I was unable to browse. 
When returned to Wi-Fi, it went fine.
Here is the output of lshw:
 *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 11
       serial: [REMOVED]
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-gen firmware=77.ad46c98b.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-77.u ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:620-61f irq:16 memory:622e1bc000-622e1bffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:5c:00.0
       logical name: enp92s0
       version: 15
       serial: [REMOVED]
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-gen firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:6c204000-6c204fff memory:6c200000-6c203fff


The most obvious problem is incorrect or missing DNS configuration, please edit your post on how you configured DNS or if you didn't.

You say, “I could ping websites no problem.”  Are you pinging by (numeric) IP address (e.g., 104.18.43.226) or by domain name (e.g., unix.stackexchange.com)?  If you are successfully pinging by domain name, why do you suspect a DNS issue?       Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

The attached Stack Overflow issue is exactly the edits I made.

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'. I don't suspect a DNS issue as I'm not sure why it would work on WiFi in that case.

Well, if my eye hurts, I don’t put a bandage on my elbow, so I’m wondering why you tried DNS fixes when pinging by domain name works.   BTW, it’s not clear to me what your code blocks for fix #3 (ip route show to default) are meant to illustrate.

If you have nothing helpful to say, you don't need to comment. In regards to your second sentence, look 3 inches down at the only answer to this question.

This is a blind shot but you need to configure DNS in the Inseego M3000 cellular hot spot
Find DNS settings there and set DNS there to 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8
Then on your local system which is Pop!_OS into /etc/resolve.conf put nameserver address that is the default gateway of your Inseego M3000 cellular hot spot
To learn default gateway run command ip route show to default on your Pop!_OS while connected to Inseego....
You finally need to restart NetworkManager on your Pop! OS
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager


Unfortunately this did not work.

Since ping by name works, DNS is not a likely cause.

@DylanRussell According to your output of ip command your ethernet adapter is not connected to Insego... it says default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3... but wlp0s20f3 is WI-FI adapter not ethernet, therefore try connecting to different LAN port if possible and regardless edit your question with output of ip -4 addr show

Will try that, thanks!

@DylanRussell In addition to ip -4 addr show please also share output of ip route show but after you connect Pop!_OS via LAN cable to Insego...
